# How to change the default markdownToHTML function?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I have some issues to change the default setting of the `markdownToHTML function`. I followed the instruction on [Customizing Markdown Rendering](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552186-Customizing-Markdown-Rendering) that is I:

1. I defined a `.css` file as `style.css` which I just copied from [Yihui Xie via Github](https://github.com/rstudio/markdown/blob/master/inst/resources/markdown.css) and changed the font-size to `30` and background-color to `blue`.

   ```
     body, td {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     background-color: blue;
     font-size: 30px;
   }
   ```
2. Set up a `source.R` with the following content:

   ```
    options(rstudio.markdownToHTML =
     function(inputFile, outputFile) {     
       require(markdown)
       markdownToHTML(inputFile, outputFile, stylesheet='style.css')  
     }
   ```

   )
3. Openend an new `R-Markdown` and put the `source.R` into the header:

   ```
     ---

     source('~/Desktop/Rdaten/source.R')

     ---

     This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting   syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
   ```

The `markdownToHTML function` still uses the default rendering. May I ask for some assistance in that respect?

I tried to `Source` source.R via `Rstudio`and run the `default` R-Markdown as well without any change in the document:

```
      ---


      ---

      This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting   syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
```

Comment: You can't source the R script in the markdown file itself because at that point the `markdownToHTML` function has already been called. You'd need to source that file in R-studio and then render the markdown file. To change the property for the document, specify a custom css in the header: see http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html (Custom CSS)

Comment: Ah Ok. So I can either use
`output:
  html_document:
    theme: united
    highlight: tango
    css: style.css` in the header or `Source` a `source.R` which refers to the `style.css`